# Can't open excel file even though have proper NTFS permissions

Tags: microsoft-excel, permissions

I have an Excel file on a server that multiple people access with no problems. A new user tried to access the file today and gets the error:

> You don't have permission to open this file error

I checked NTFS permssions and he has modify permissions, I even gave him full access but the error persists. He is able to drill down via file explorer and see the file with no problem just can't open the file. Why would just this one user not be able to open the file?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my researching, you can follow below steps to have a check:

1. On the root folder, right click, select properties, select security tab.
2. Click Advanced
3. The window that pops up should show the current owner. Click "Change." The "Select User or Group" pop up box appears.
4. In the text box, type in your current user name (you should be an admin), and hit the "Check Names" button. Your name will be replaced with the "official" system name (i.e.,preceded by computer name and back slash).
5. Click OK
6. The box disappears, sending you back to the Advanced Security Settings window.
7. A new tick box appears below owner, with the text "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" Select this tick box.
8. I also selected the tick box "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object", but I think I had to run this twice - once with this box ticked and once without.
9. Make sure that "everyone" appears on the Permission entries window, if not, click add. The same box that appears in step 4 shows up again. Type everyone, click "Check Names" and then "OK"
10. Hit apply

Reference: [the thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-security/permission-error-failed-to-enumerate-objects-in/93ea883f-853f-4981-a697-928bfbc71642?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=kXQk6*ivFEQ&ranSiteID=kXQk6.ivFEQ-OpUQ2eIUXaBvRP1Y25ETDQ&epi=kXQk6.ivFEQ-OpUQ2eIUXaBvRP1Y25ETDQ&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=(ir__nyjvc0jjv0kfr3wn0h20wk909m2xji3anerd6acx00)(7593)(1243925)(kXQk6.ivFEQ-OpUQ2eIUXaBvRP1Y25ETDQ)()&irclickid=_nyjvc0jjv0kfr3wn0h20wk909m2xji3anerd6acx00).

Comment: This does not apply, the NTFS permissions are applied to the folder and the file it's self with no problems.